# Full height Web Application

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i would like to make my website utilize the full height of the browser. I have tried all the usual css to no avail. 
id like the Sidebar and main content to fill the full height of the browser while the header should stay the fixed height.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damo642/Yu8YU/)

Any help appreciated
thanks
Damo

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>TestSite</title>
    <link href="assets/css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="HeaderWrapper">
                <div id="Header">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ContentWrapper">

                <div id="Sidebar">

                </div>
                <div id="Content" style="border: thin solid #666666"  class="Tabs">
                </div>
                <!-- end of content -->        
            </div>
            <!-- end of wrapper -->
            <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**

```
#HeaderWrapper 
{
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:0px;    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#99CCFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#9CF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #9CF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */   

    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    border-bottom:thin solid #FFFFFF;

}

#Header
{    

    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    border-radius: 5px;    



}

#ContentWrapper 
{
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    border-radius: 5px;    


}


/* sidebar */

#Sidebar {

    float: left;
    width: 184px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:800px;
    border: thin solid #666666;
    padding:0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:6px;
    margin-left:0px;    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 


}


/* end of sidebar -->

/* content */

#Content {
    float: left;
    width: 824px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    min-height:800px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
}
/* End content */



/* End content */
html,body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.5em;     
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003366', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#036), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #036,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    height: 100%;    

}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive decided not to reinvent the wheel and use this.
For anyone reading this please follow this advice or you will go mad!!
[Description of Solution](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/)

which leads me to this

[Solution](http://www.alistapart.com/d/conflictingabsolutepositions/layout-1.html)

Answer (score 4):

I know somebody already provided a solution with javascript but just in case you want pure CSS then, try setting the height of your #ContentWrapper, UpdatePanel, and form to 100%.

Put this in the head section

```
<style type="text/css">
    #<%=UpdatePanel.ClientID%> 
    {
        height: 100%;    
    }
</style>
```

Update your CSS file:

```
#ContentWrapper 
{
    height: 100%;
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    border-radius: 5px;    
}

html,body, form {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.5em;     
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003366', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#036), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #036,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    height: 100%;    

}​
```

Comment: Or you can add a surrounding div with height:auto !important;height:100%;margin:auto;min-height:100%;

Comment: I'm a fan of pure CSS for this. +1

Comment: hi, id like to use pure CSS also. I tried your code and get the following error in Visual studio when the page tries to load "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)." - In the HTML (Prior to compile within visual studio) it give an error before compile - "Missing a selector in the Style rule"

Comment: note it looks like the error is due to the code:  <style type="text/css">
    #<%=UpdatePanel.ClientID%> 
    {
        height: 100%;    
    }
</style>

Comment: user1438082, do you have UpdatePanel control in your page? Also, make sure that your <head> is configured runat="server"

Comment: <head> has runat ="server". i do have an update panel though?

Comment: user1438082, try #<%# UpdatePanel.ClientID%> --- Changed the = to #

Comment: hi, i still get an error within visual studio stating "missing a selector in the style rule"     <style type="text/css">
    #<%#UpdatePanel.ClientID%> 
    {
        height: 100%;    
    }
</style>

Comment: when i put it into jsfiddle it doesnt work either. http://jsfiddle.net/damo642/Yu8YU/9/

Comment: thanks for your help. please see my solution below. working now fullscreen! damo

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always set the height of the elements you want via JavaScript ([here is an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu8YU/7/))

```
var height = $(window).height()-$("#HeaderWrapper").height()-10;
$("#Sidebar,#Content").css("height", height);
```

You would want to add this code on the resize event like this `$(window).resize(function() {});` (jsFiddle seems to get in the way of modifying this event)

Also I removed the min-height and made the content pane use overflow-y: scroll while working on this because I thought it would work better and support a wider range of browsers, but this is not needed for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/KZurX/11/

I have decreased the 768 number to account for the small size of the test window in jsFiddle. You can see that the side bar and main content fill the window when the window height becomes larger  than the specified value. *Note: jsFiddle does not run server side code, so your asp.net controls are unnecessary.*

Comment: apologies. i have clarified the question. i simply want a full height application.

Comment: What do you mean? It is full height. Am I misunderstanding you? - you wanted the main content div and sidebar div to fill the browser and this is what my solution does.

Comment: Ok I see your edit, but I still don't understand. The header already maintains a fixed height. What browser are you testing this in? I am using Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use media queries, like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body{
        height:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i have clarified the question. please ignore 768px request.